# View is not getting rendered properly

Tags: jquery, backbone.js, requirejs, backbone-views

I am working in an existing Backbone Project. I am working on Dashboard page. In this page we have separate views for each section, I am working on the `mypage` section

Dashboard js has the following code

```
     require(['project/home/mypage'], function(MyPage) {    
            myPage = new MyPage();
            $(self.el).find("#my-page").html(mypage.render(self));

         });

    require([ 'project/home/differentpage' ], function(DifferentPage) {
            differentPage = new DifferentPage();
            $(self.el).find("#different-page").html(differentPage.render());

        });
```

mypage.js file look like this. It is extending the view from another javascript file and after rendering it is calling the overridden `renderComments` method to update the view.

```
render : function(parent) {
  require(['project/homepage'], function(HomePage){
  var mypage = HomePage.extend({
    render:function() {
       $(this.el).html('<div id='+this.rowContainer()+'> </div>');
       return this;
    },
    rowContainer: function(){
        return 'rowList';
    },
    renderComments: function(responseJson, loadMoreRows){
         // My Logic for this page goes here. I am adding few rows to the view
    }
   });
  var mytempPage =new HomePage();
  var trayEl = mytemppage.render().el;
  trayEl.renderComments();
  $(this.el).html(trayEl);

   return this;
 }
```

The view is getting the`div` tag with id `rowList` but it is not getting the row added. When I debugged using inspect element, the renderComments method is invoked.

Am I missing anything here. Appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

`var mytempPage =new HomePage();`

creates a new element

`var trayEl = mytempPage.render().el;`

trayEl is assigned to the .el property...of the result of the render 
function (it returns 'this'...so it's just the .el itself)

`trayEl.renderComments();`

renderComments currently returns undefined/does nothing...so it looks like you're just passing the .el itself to html, which shouldn't render anything else.

`$(this.el).html(trayEl);`

Remember, to change the html here, trayEl needs to be a html string.
Try passsing in some raw html for the comments want to add, and see if that works.